# Layout issue when using Linear Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have two text and an arrow mark to the end. So I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeltext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Specification"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelselected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Specification down"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I am still getting :

[image]

I thought if we put android:gravity="right" the whole image goes to the right but this didn't move?

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: set gravity to right on layout of textview

Comment: change orientacion "horizontal"

Comment: it will layout_gravity not just gravity

Comment: Use relative layout instead of linear layout and make             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE :**

1. first put `LinearLayout`with `horizontal` orientation
2. then put another 2 `LinearLayout`inside it and set the `layout_weight` as your desire
3. then add anything that you want inside them.

thats all....

here is the corrected code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeltext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Specification" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelselected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Specification down"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way.

Screenshot reference:

[image]

I did it by set **match_parent** width to `TextView` and assigning **drawableRight** property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeltext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_next"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Specification" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelselected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Specification down" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `ImageView` you can set your icon as a drawable to your `TextView` and set its width to `match_parent`

```
<TextView
...
android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_icon"/>
```

also I think your IDE will suggest you to remove your `LinearLayout` , `TextView` and `ImageView` and use my solution because using one widget instead of three is always better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout and try. I am just giving hint. to place text and image in same line with distributed layout_weight. You can tweak as per your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeltext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Specification"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelselected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Specification down"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this with your Upper Layout. you need to use layout_gravity="right" for imageView.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeltext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="Specification"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this it will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labeltext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Specification" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelselected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Specification down" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` like here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labeltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Specification"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelselected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Specification down"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add weight to `lateltext` textView as 1

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labeltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Specification"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```